# Android: String that should be empty has strange content

Tags: java, android

I have a very strange bug here.

I set a string empty:

```
String s = "";
```

But sometimes when I later use it, it contains:

```
"java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$NonfairSync@2105f068[State = 0, empty queue]"
```

This happens in a background thread.

Any ideas how this is possible?

**Update:**

I was asked to provide more code.
The full code would be too much, but here is more information:
The problem occurs in a background task started with AsyncTask.
I am doing nothing more than this:

```
String s = "";
String t = "";
...
... Here happens some other stuff, that does not use s or t
...
s += "x";
t += "y" + s + "z";
Log.d("TEST", t);

Output most of the time: "yxz"
Output sometimes: "yjava.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$NonfairSync@2105f068[State = 0, empty queue]xz"
```

I am using Java version 7 update 51

Comment: More code is necessary. Where all is `s` used and where do you print or log the `s` string?

Comment: your problem is about thread / lock and not about empty string

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a Deadlock to me.

Read about this [Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock) and [here](http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=7011862) too.

Try upgrading to the latest Java version - it might solve the problem.

Comment: Maybe there is a Deadlock. But I still don't unterstand: How does the message get into the string?